# How to setup nginx for Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, nginx, laravel-nova

I use laravel nova on subdomain 'admin.mydomain.com'. How do I setup nginx to serve my laravel app on mydomain.com and serve laravel nova admin panel on admin.mydomain.com ?
For hosting my main app I followed this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-laravel-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04 tutorial on digital ocean. I also tried creating new nginx configuration called admin.mydomain.com a copied the config from the app. But it did not really work.

Comment: I already fixed this issues.

Comment: Also added answer that fixes this problem.

Comment: I just have to wait 2-3 days to accept my answer because stackoverflow wont let me do it now.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding my subdomain to existing config that my app uses.
Just appended admin.mydomain.com to server_name in nginx config.

```
server{

   server_name mydomain.com admin.mydomain.com;
   ...
}
```